# How to call a JavaScript function from a string value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a form I have a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="callback_function" value="myFunction" />
```

Now some JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('.dataRow').click(function(){
        if($('#callback_function').val()){
            //same as executing myFunction();
            eval($('#callback_function').val()+'();');
        }
    });
</script>
```

This works but seems very inelegant.  Is there a way to do this without using `eval`?

Comment: Why can't you just put `myFunction` in the code, instead of using a hidden input?

Comment: because the function (in this case 'myFunction') is variable, and is not a part of the document fragment which gets loaded by Ajax.  the function pre-exists the script I showed

Comment: @Colin - yes, that post you referenced covers this very well, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the function is global (a property of `window`) so we don't need to `eval` it at all:

```
<script>
$('.dataRow').click(function(){
   var fnName = $('#callback_function').val();
   if(fnName && window[fnName]) {
       window[fnName]();
   }
});
</script>
```